# Aws integration spring: Cannot download a file within a folder

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-boot, spring-integration

The below code is trying downloaded a single file from within a folder on S3. It is using the message handler below.

NOTE: The code below works for a file that is placed within the root directory of the S3 bucket. It does not work for a file placed in a folder.

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "s3Channel")
    public MessageHandler s3Handler() {
       ExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
       S3MessageHandler s3MessageHandler = new S3MessageHandler(amazonS3(), "test.queue", true);
       s3MessageHandler.setOutputChannel(this.channel);
       s3MessageHandler.setCommand(S3MessageHandler.Command.DOWNLOAD);
       s3MessageHandler.setKeyExpression(PARSER.parseExpression("payload instanceof T(java.io.File) ? payload.name : headers.key"));
       s3MessageHandler.setObjectAclExpression(new ValueExpression<>(CannedAccessControlList.PublicReadWrite));
       return s3MessageHandler;
}
```

Using the payload:

```
 Message<?> payload = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new File("test/s3testfile.xml")).build();

 this.s3ProcessChannel.send(payload);
```

The following stack trace occurs downloading a file from with a folder.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [s3MessageHandler]; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found;)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel.sendInternal(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:91) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.rapid7.live.assessment.aws.inbound.channels.SqsAssessmentMessageChannel.send(SqsAssessmentMessageChannel.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-integration-aws-1.0.0.M1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationQueueMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:154) ~[spring-integration-aws-1.0.0.M1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:389) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.executeMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:181) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.1.0.RC1.jar:1.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$MessageExecutor.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:314) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.1.0.RC1.jar:1.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:368) [spring-cloud-aws-messaging-1.1.0.RC1.jar:1.1.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:251) [spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

The file does exist in the correct bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is here that `File.getName()` returns only **file name**, without any parent dirs.

Consider change your `keyExpression` to the :

```
"payload instanceof T(java.io.File) ? payload.path : headers.key"
```

Or just don't reply on the File payload but always specify the proper `key` in the headers.